# Strict Inequality for Fourier Coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I've been trying to solve this inequality but I only get the obvious part which is the $\leq$ part. I need the $<$. The problem is the following:

Given a subset $A\subset [0,1)$ of measure not $0$, prove the following strict inequality:
$$
|\widehat{\chi_A}(n)| = \bigg|\int_A e^{2\pi i n x} d x \bigg| < |A|
$$

where $\widehat{\chi_A}(n)$ denotes the $n$-th Fourier coefficient of the function $\chi_A$, that is, $1$ in $A$ and $0$ outside.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to assume $n\ne0$. It's obvious that in fact $\widehat{\chi_A}(0)=|A|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^{2\pi inx}$. If equality holds then $\int_A f(x)dx=|A|e^{it}$ for some real $t$. Hence  $\int_A [e^{-it}f(x)-1]dx=0$. Taking real part we get $\int_A [\cos (2\pi  nx-t)-1]dx=0$. The integrand is $\leq 0$ so this implies $\cos (2\pi  nx-t)-1=0$ for almost all $x \in A$. In other words $2\pi  nx-t \in 2\pi \mathbb Z$ for almost all $x$. can you get a contradiction from this? [Hint: take $x,x'$ with $x-x'$ irrational]. Works only if $n \neq 0$. Thanks to David Ullrich for pointing out.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much.

Comment: Of course there's no contradiction if $n=0$.

Comment: Yes, I forgot writing $n\not=0$ in the hypothesis.